# switch command in C# not working

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I'm new to C# and I'm practising by coding a simple Rock, Paper Scissors game, however I have a problem with my "switch" command.
I want the user to input either Rock, Paper or Scissors, and then take the input and go to a particular case, however I can't figure out how to do it.

```
    {
        //random number generator
            Random random = new Random();
            int randomNumber = random.Next(1,4);

        //user input
            Console.WriteLine("PLease Enter Rock, Paper or Scissors");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

        //compare input and random number
        switch (input)
        {
            case Rock:
                if (randomNumber == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("It's a draw, computer also chose Rock");
                }
                else if (randomNumber == 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You loose, computer chose Paper");
                }
                else if (randomNumber == 3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You win, computer chose Scissors");
                }
                break;

            case Paper:
                if (randomNumber == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You win, computer chose Rock");
                }
                else if (randomNumber == 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("It's a draw, computer also chose Paper");
                }
                else if (randomNumber == 3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You loose, computer chose Scissors");

                }
                break;

            case Scissors:
                if (randomNumber == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You loose, computer chose Rock");
                }
                else if (randomNumber == 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You win, computer chose Paper");
                }
                else if (randomNumber == 3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("It's a draw, computer chose Scissors");

                }
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Do you have `Rock`, `Paper`, and `Scissors` defined somewhere? The code you've shown shouldn't compile. Try putting the cases in double quotes (e.g. `case "Rock":`)

Comment: Since you are taking input as string then you have to check as string in case statement, like case "Rock"

Comment: What seems to be the issue here? You are using quotations around Rock, Paper and Scissors, right?

Comment: Specifically, what error are you getting? You need to state that in your question.

Comment: Always include error messages, expected vs actual results etc. There is no real question here now.

Comment: Thank you guys, the problem was I had not used quotation marks around my "cases"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cases must be written as string literals (in quotes):

```
switch (input)
{
    case "Rock":
        // ...
        break;

    case "Paper":
        // ...
        break;

    case "Scissors":
        // ...
        break;
}
```

Or alternatively, define some variables that hold these values, e.g.

```
string Rock = "Rock";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the cases as string:

```
...
case "Rock":
...
```